# BufferedReader Exception

Tags: java

I have used:

```
    try {
        URL _url = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) _url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            teste = teste + line;
        }
        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception===" + e);
        return null;
    }

    return teste;
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Exception StackTrace: 
     java.net.UnknownHostException: api
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:225)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:488)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:424)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:538)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:221)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:304)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:935)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:853)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1402)
```

Comment: Please remove this image and post your real code.

Comment: By the way, the error message is very explicit. Did you at least **read it**?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that that you cannot connect to your URL.`UnknownHostException` suggests that the address you are trying to connect to doesn't exist.